# How to set password on backend user-creation?

Tags: user-account

Is it possible to set the password on backend CMS user-creation in CiviCRM?
I think I saw this in an older CiviCRM-version... 
Form ID = Useradd

Comment: Can you CMS name and version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 5.37 there was a [bug](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2605) that hid the password field. This is fixed in the 5.37 branch but 5.37.3 hasn't been released yet, otherwise it will be in 5.38. If you're on 5.37 you can just replace the CRM/Contact/Form/Task/Useradd.php file with this one: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/5.37/CRM/Contact/Form/Task/Useradd.php

Note that in wordpress if the wordpress configuration says to allow anyone to register, then the password field is intentionally hidden because it was decided that the user should set their own password using the link in the email.

Comment: This is it, THANK YOU VERY MUCH!